# htaccess 301 redirect subdirectory one level deeper - why is this not working?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

it is probably a stupid question, but I have real troubles figuring out, how to redirect

/products to /products/item

It is a simple redirect, no regex needed. The toplevel site /products should just always redirect to /products/item

I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) /products/item/$1
</IfModule>
```

I receive the error, that the webserver is redirecting in an infinite loop. That might be because of the rest of the htaccess file. Which looks like that:

```
# Custom Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) /products/item/$1
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But the strangest thing: When I load the page, I get the error. When I then hit reload, it works???

Thanks for your help! ole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/?$ /products/item
```

The /? allows it to match both /products and /products/

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

> RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) /products/item/$1

`/products(.*)` will also match `/products/item` and will result in the infinite redirect you observed.

You can try the following rule instead

```
#if its not already products/item, redirect to products/item
RewriteRule ^(products)/(?!item/)(.*)$ $1/item/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Place this rule right after the `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But with this rule I will end up with /products/ redirecting to /products/item/item

Comment: @ole_berlin What URL did you test with or are you guessing that will be the result?

Comment: hey, the url I'm testing with is /products and the result is /products/item/item

Comment: @ole_berlin Using just `/products` should not match, and does not when I test as the Rule requires a trailing `/` to match i.e. this rule is not responsible for the redirect Do you have any other .htaccess rules besides the ones posted above? I am also assuming you removed the original redirect match? You also need to test in private browsing mode, or clear your browser cache to remove the  301 redirects cached from your previous `RedirectMatch` rule ...

Comment: Ok, good thought with the private browsing mode. But I don't want to redirect /products/something, I want to redirect /products/ to /products/item , so one level deeper. /products/item is also an absolute path, a permalink so to say. Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution: RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/?$ /products/item

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $0 !^products/item
RewriteRule ^(products)(.*)$ $1/item$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```